# Divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I had a job interview a few weeks ago and I was asked to design a divide and conquer algorithm. I could not solve the problem, but they just called me for a second interview! Here is the question:

we are giving as input two n-element arrays A[0..n − 1] and B[0..n − 1] (which
are not necessarily sorted) of integers, and an integer value. Give an O(nlogn) divide and conquer algorithm that determines if there exist distinct values i, j (that is, i != j) such that A[i] + B[j] = value. Your algorithm should return True if i, j exists, and return False otherwise. You may assume that the elements in A are distinct, and the elements in B are distinct.

can anybody solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: How did you try to solve this problem? and where did you get stuck?

Comment: it is extremely easy if we don't use divide and conquer(brute force). but I have no idea how to approach this problem using divide and conquer method. I was hoping if somebody at least could give me hint

Comment: "if there exist distinct values i, j (that is, i != j)": this is a highly dubious requirement. It makes little sense to require distinct indexes as the elements are drawn from different arrays, and distinct values are not expressed by i != j but A[i] != B[j]. Another interpretation could be "are there distinct pairs such that...".

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP wants to find the pairs such that both element should not have same original index.

Comment: @SanketMakani: this is a nasty requirement as it compels you to keep track of the original indexes in case you shuffle the arrays.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Yes that would be the only overhead to do this task in `O(n log n)` complexity but this might be a valid argument of interviewer as they require you to think in both memory and time optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm does not use Divide and Conquer but it is one of the solutions.
You need to sort both the arrays, maintaining the indexes of the elements maybe sorting an array of pairs `(elem, index)`. This takes `O(n log n)` time.

Then you can apply the merge algorithm to check if there two elements such that A[i]+B[j] = value. This would `O(n)`

Overall time complexity will be `O(n log n)`

Comment: Where is D&C ??

Comment: There is no D&C in my algorithm. I just posted a possible solution. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is..

1. Sort any of the array. Here we sort array A. Sort it with the `Merge Sort` algorithm which is a `Divide and Conquer` algorithm.
2. Then for each element of B, Search for `Required Value- Element of B` in array A by `Binary Search`. Again this is a `Divide and Conquer` algorithm.
3. If you find the element `Required Value - Element of B` from an Array A then Both element makes pair such that `Element of A + Element of B = Required Value`.

So here for Time Complexity, `A` has `N` elements so `Merge Sort` will take `O(N log N)` and We do `Binary Search` for each element of B(Total N elements) Which takes `O(N log N)`. So total time complexity would be `O(N log N)`.

As you have mentioned you require to check for `i != j` if `A[i] + B[j] = value` then here you can take 2D array of size `N * 2`. Each element is paired with its original index as second element of the each row. Sorting would be done according the the data stored in the first element. Then when you find the element, You can compare both elements original indexes and return the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *hashing*. Even if it's *not the way* you are supposed to solve the problem, it's worth mentioning since hashing has a better time complexity `O(n)` v. `O(n*log(n))` and that's why more efficient.

1. Turn `A` into a *hashset* (or *dictionary* if we want `i` index) - `O(n)`
2. Scan `B` and check if there's `value - B[j]` in the hashset (dictionary) - `O(n)`

So you have an `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)` algorithm (which is *better* that required `(O n * log(n))`, however the solution is **NOT** Divide and Conquer):

Sample C# implementation

```
  int[] A = new int[] { 7, 9, 5, 3, 47, 89, 1 };
  int[] B = new int[] { 5, 7, 3, 4, 21, 59, 0 };

  int value = 106; // 47 + 59 = A[4] + B[5]

  // Turn A into a dictionary: key = item's value; value = item's key 
  var dict = A
    .Select((val, index) => new {
      v = val,
      i = index, })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.v, item => item.i);

  int i = -1;
  int j = -1;

  // Scan B array
  for (int k = 0; k < B.Length; ++k) {
    if (dict.TryGetValue(value - B[k], out i)) {
      // Solution found: {i, j} 
      j = k;

      // if you want any solution then break
      break;

      // scan further (comment out "break") if you want all pairs
    }
  }

  Console.Write(j >= 0 ? $"{i} {j}" : "No solution");
```

Comment: This solution is maybe the less D&C so far.

Comment: This is the easiest solution for this type of questions but still OP didn't ask for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems hard to achieve without sorting.

If you leave the arrays unsorted, checking for existence of `A[i]+B[j] = Value` takes time `Ω(n)` for fixed `i`, then checking for all `i` takes `Θ(n²)`, unless you find a trick to put some order in `B`.

Balanced Divide & Conquer on the unsorted arrays doesn't seem any better: if you divide `A` and `B` in two halves, the solution can lie in one of `Al/Bl`, `Al/Br`, `Ar/Bl`, `Ar/Br` and this yields a recurrence `T(n) = 4 T(n/2)`, which has a quadratic solution.

If sorting is allowed, the solution by Sanket Makani is a possibility but you do better in terms of time complexity for the search phase.

Indeed, assume `A` and `B` now sorted and consider the 2D function `A[i]+B[j]`, which is monotonic in both directions `i` and `j`. Then the domain `A[i]+B[j] ≤ Value` is limited by a monotonic curve `j = f(i)` or equivalently `i = g(j)`. But strict equality `A[i]+B[j] = Value` must be checked exhaustively for all points of the curve and one cannot avoid to evaluate `f` everywhere in the worst case.

Starting from `i = 0`, you obtain `f(i)` by dichotomic search. Then you can follow the border curve incrementally. You will perform `n` step in the `i` direction, and at most `n` steps in the `j` direction, so that the complexity remains bounded by `O(n)`, which is optimal.

Below, an example showing the areas with a sum below and above the target value (there are two matches).

[image]

This optimal solution has little to do with Divide & Conquer. It is maybe possible to design a variant based on the evaluation of the sum at a central point, which allows to discard a whole quadrant, but that would be pretty artificial.

Comment: This is a really confusing explanation of "start at the beginning of A and the end of B, repeatedly move to the next element of A if the sum is smaller than the target value or the previous element of B if it's greater. This works because any element to the left of A is smaller, thus the sum will be smaller, similarly for B".

Comment: Nice approach for searching but I don't agree that this is more efficient that the approach I have given. Time complexities are same for both the algorithms `O(n log n)`. If we count total iterations then your approach has `2 * n log n` for sorting both the arrays and `n` for seaching while in my approach we do sorting for only one array and for another array we do binary seach for each element so total iterations would be `n log n + n*(log n) = 2* n log n`. At first your approach seems to be more time-efficient than mine but actually it has overhead of  `n` over my approach.

Comment: @SanketMakani: I specified "for the search phase" explicitly, i.e. assuming that the arrays are sorted. But it is enough to sort only one array. Actually my argument shows that it is no use to sort both. And dichotomic search is overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I agree on that point that if both the arrays are sorted then no need to do dichotomic search. In that case we can find the pair by just traversing both the arrays only once with `O(n)` time-complexity.

Comment: @SanketMakani: ooops, my previous comment was wrong, you do need to sort both to perform linear search. Now it is not possible to be conclusive about which approach is the fastest, as we are dealing with asymptotic complexities only.